# game logic does not show the real winner name

Tags: python, logic

I have wrote a simple program that generates a randint and 2 player have to guess the number.

Everything is alright except showing the actual player name. I am a beginner and i really appreciate if suggestions to solve the problem do not require change the whole logic of the game. I am sure it can be better but i am selling help with that specific issue.

```py
def take_player_guess(current_player):
    global player_1
    global player_2
    num = random.randint(0,10) 
    guessed = set()
    player_guess = None

    while player_guess != num:
        print("{}'s Turn ".format(current_player)) #


        if current_player == player_1:
            current_player = player_2

        elif current_player == player_2:
            current_player = player_1

        try:
            player_guess = int(input("Please enter an integer value as a guess >> "))

            if player_guess > num:
                print("Guess lower!")
                guessed.add(player_guess)
                print(guessed) 

            elif player_guess < num:
                print("Guess higher!")
                guessed.add(player_guess)
                print(guessed)
        except:
            print("input must be an integer")
        else:
            pass     



def check_for_winner(current_player): # done 
    global winner
    global num
    #global current_player

    if player_guess == num:
        current_player == winner
        print("Congratulations {}, You have won!".format(current_player))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow your logic with these solution, although I have to say, that it should be done other way.
The problem is, that I think you did not posted full code - how do you run it, and where do you check, if the player is winner.

I was able to do it that way:

```py
import random

def take_player_guess(current_player):
    global player_1
    global player_2
    global player_guess
    global num
    num = random.randint(0,10) 
    guessed = set()
    player_guess = None

    while player_guess != num:

        if current_player == player_1:
            current_player = player_2

        elif current_player == player_2:
            current_player = player_1

        print("{}'s Turn ".format(current_player)) #

        try:
            player_guess = int(input("Please enter an integer value as a guess >> "))

            if player_guess > num:
                print("Guess lower!")
                guessed.add(player_guess)
                print(guessed) 

            elif player_guess < num:
                print("Guess higher!")
                guessed.add(player_guess)
                print(guessed)

            check_for_winner(current_player)
        except Exception as e:
            print("input must be an integer", e)
        else:
            pass     



def check_for_winner(current_player): # done 
    #global current_player

    if player_guess == num:
        print("Congratulations {}, You have won!".format(current_player))


player_1 = 'me'
player_2 = 'you'
take_player_guess(player_1)
```

But i have to say - use Classes, and do it other way.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is true. This is not the whole block of code. i have tried everything to solve the issue. i believe it is with defining global variables( current_player = player_1 or player_2).

Comment: tried it! same issue. winner of the game also seems to be random. test it many times and see. i still appreciate your reply of course.

Comment: Well, that was stupid problem with printing before assignment - I edited code, seems to be ok.